# Search bar and webview in separate views?

Tags: iphone, ios, search, uiwebview, uitextfield

Is it possible in xcode 4.2 to have a UITextField search bar in one view that connects to a UIWebView in a second view controller? I can get it to search if the search bar and the webView are in the same view controller. But when I have the webview in a separate view controller the webview connection wont connect in storyboard.

For examples sake:
Just like the Google homepage. The main page only has a search bar. Once you search, it takes you to a separate page showing the results.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it's possible. I suggest you to use a @property/@synthesize object on the receiver UIViewController (the one with the UIWebView) that it's initialized/filled from the calling viewController with the search string that you want to use.